# Updating webservice, without updating the web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have a webservice with an assembly added in the system.web\assemblies section of the web.config file:

```
<add assembly="MyWebservice, 
    Version=1.0.0.36211, 
    Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b9f7c69b7e2ca2dc" />
```

The problem is that if i put out an update, the config file has to be updated too, even though nothing has changed but the version number in that one line.  This creates a headache for the people running this service and wanting an update. They might have the service installed on several different locations on the same server with their own personal customizations.  An update forces them to go through all their folders and update this one file.  Is it possible to this in code?  The Dll is listed in the config because of a few IHttpHandlers i have defined.  This is a .NET 4 webservice written in C#.

Comment: Does it still work if you just remove the `Version=` completely?

Answer (score 3):

We always exclude the version, culture, and publickeytoken from the assembly entries for this very reason. There are some DLLs that require this, mainly for licensing, but in your case, it should work perfectly well to remove that info.

You should be able to change it to:

```
<add assembly="MyWebservice"/>
```

We also do the same for assemblies added to projects (we manually edit the csproj or vbproj files) and for licenses.licx, except where the component vendor specifically requires a version.

Comment: Doesn't this allow the DLL to be switched out and can cause a vulnerability? I mean security may or may not be a factor to the user.

Comment: I'm pretty sure .NET will try to resolve the DLL with the information you give it.  Meaning, you can give it a public key but not specify a version number.  This would still be pretty secure, as the public key tokens are difficult if not impossible to change.

Comment: This causes a problem if there are more than one version of the DLL in the GAC right?  Or does my service just look for the one its bound to during compilation?

Comment: Oh, if you're installing the web service to the GAC, then I believe that this will cause a problem, but we never install to the GAC, so I am not exactly sure what it does. My guess is that it will look for the version referenced at compile time, but I am not 100% certain of that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try this:

```
<add assembly="MyWebservice, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b9f7c69b7e2ca2dc"/>
```